# How to find first occurrence of one of a sequence of characters in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I would like to write a simple query to find the first occurrence of either ',' or ';' in a string within T-SQL. Is there any easy way to do this?

In other databases I would use a regular expression such as [,;] but these aren't available in T-SQL.

The only solution I can think of is to have a long list of nested if .. else statements but that doesn't appeal.

Answer (score 7):

Try PATINDEX...

```
select patindex('%,%', my_column)
from my_table
```

Comment: `'%[;,]%'` would catch both `;` and `,`, I believe: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179884.aspx

Comment: Thanks, '%[;,]%' works like a charm. I had read the documentation for PATINDEX but from that reading didn't think that this would work.

Comment: Just for you to know, the first parameter in patindex is a regular expression. http://dbaspot.com/sqlserver-programming/467799-patindex-regular-expression.html

Comment: The first parameter in `PATINDEX` is not a regular expression, as one of the first comments in that thread points out. There are lots of things you can express with a regular expression but not with a pattern that `PATINDEX` can understand.

Answer (score 0):

I am vastly ignorant of T-SQL, but looking at Microsoft's documentation it seems like `CHARINDEX` will find the first occurrence of a single character (or in fact of any string), and you can just call it twice (once for `,` and once for `;`) and see which one occurs first. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms186323%28v=sql.90%29.aspx .

Comment: Gareth, that is what I am trying to avoid doing. Because after searching for each character separately you end up with a huge nested if statement that is hard to understand and maintain.

Comment: I see you've got an answer you're happy with -- but if you feel like gratifying my curiosity, could you explain why you'd end up with a huge nested if statement using `CHARINDEX` but not, e.g., with `PATINDEX`? (E.g., are you actually envisaging a situation where there are a lot more than 2 characters that you're looking for?)